# Get remote port of a connected TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

For the purposes of constructing a rate limiter I need to be able to distinguish different users being routed through the same gateway.  So if I have 100 clients with the same IP address I would like to tell them apart by what port they are associated with on the remote gateway/host/router.

I can get the IP easily with:

```
string clientIPAddress = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
```

Is there some way similarly to get the remote port number for the client?  Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var port = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port
```

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.port.aspx

HTH.